# Encoding Speex Into a SWF Version 10 Sound Stream

Tags: flash, speex

Adobe's "SWF File Format Specification v10" says that Speex encoded data can be used for streaming sound (a little clarification of the "streaming sound" definition here: "The SWF file format supports a streaming sound mode where sound data is played and downloaded in tight synchronization with the timeline. In this mode, sound packets are stored with each frame." - this has nothing to do with any FMS streaming, no ActionScript needed - just plain SWF).

This should be accomplished by using a single SoundStreamHead2 tag with StreamSoundCompression set to 11 (which means "Speex", as stated in the abovementioned Specification) and then N pairs of ShowFrame and SoundStreamBlock tags. However, this does not work - Flash Player plays no sound when playing the SWF generated by me this way. Please note, that I am capable of generating such SWFs containing streamed MP3 or PCM data, which then play perfectly. Just not Speex...

I strictly conform to the Specification: `http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/swf/pdf/swf_file_format_spec_v10.pdf`, page 220.

I tried the streaming sound approach as well as the event sound - both do not work.

Moreover, I was not able to find (anywhere on the Internet) any sample SWF with streaming sound (nor event sound) encoded in Speex. Do they even exist? Anyway, Flash CS5.5 is not capable of generating them...

I would just like to know whether Speex support for SWF streaming sound can be found anywhere else than in the Specification. (I know that FLV can contain Speex and that Flash Player can stream Speex from a microphone and that FMS can stream Speex to its clients, but this is not what I am asking for)

Kind regards,

JK

Answer (score 0):

I found the FLV file format documentation more useful. Look [here](http://download.macromedia.com/f4v/video_file_format_spec_v10_1.pdf) (Page 70) for the tag format after that just put Speex encoded output.

Just remember that flash only support 16KHz/Mono/16bit when encoded using Speex

Comment: Is your point that only FLV files are allowed to contain Speex data? Can you confirm that the SWF specification is wrong about storing Speex (just like MP3) inside an SWF file? (I have already known about the FLV)

Comment: After rereading your question I realized that I answer the wrong question and that I need more coffee. I have not tried to embed Speex data into a SWF.